# Count for one or more criteria

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, filtering

I have an Excel sheet with columns A:AS, each column being a category with either a "Y" or an "N" in each row for the category:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h71pk.png]

I would like to count all the rows that have a "Y" in ONE OR MORE of the columns AA, AB, AK, AM, AP, or AQ.

Comment: This is a simple operation.  Do you have a question?

Comment: "I want to count all the rows" - what do you mean? Do you want a total number of times "Y" appears? Or do you want the row numbers for each column that "Y" appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula on row 2 in one column (let's call it `AX`) and drag it down:

```
' Column AX
=OR(AA2="Y",AB2="Y",AK2="Y",AM2="Y",AP2="Y",AQ2="Y")

' Column AY
=COUNTIF(AX:AX,TRUE)
```

Comment: This would only return `TRUE` - I think OP is looking for a Count.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks, the OP wasn't clear about what he wanted